# Counting number of matches in number of lines for regex search

Tags: regular-expressions, search

I have functions that run `re-search-forward` and gather its output into a buffer.

```el
(defun my-search (pattern)
  "Uses `re-search-forward` to return matching lines."
  (let ((src)
    (rslt))
    (progn 
      (goto-char (re-search-forward pattern))
      (save-excursion
       (setq rslt (buffer-substring (progn (beginning-of-line-text)(point))
                    (progn (end-of-line) (point)))))
      (format "%s\n\n" rslt))))


(defun my-search-results ()
"Iterate through buffer with `my-search` and gather matching lines into a buffer."
  (interactive)
    (let ((pattern (read-regexp "Regex Pattern to Search for: "))
    (rslt (generate-new-buffer "*Search Results*"))
    (match 0)
    (nlines 0)
    (current-line 0))
        (while (not (eq (ignore-errors (save-excursion (re-search-forward pattern))) nil))
    (princ (my-search pattern) rslt)
    (incf match))
    (switch-to-buffer "*Search Results*")))
```

We all know that `Occur` will display `"%d matches in %d lines."` in its search result. How do we do the same for these functions without repetition when there is more than one match in a line?

Currently, `match` would keep track of the number of iteration cycles, which should be equivalent to the number of matching pattern found.

Adding an `if` clause to `my-search-results` doesn't solve the problem.

```el
(defun my-search-results ()
  (interactive)
    (let ((pattern (read-regexp "Regex Pattern to Search for: "))
    (rslt (generate-new-buffer "*Search Results*"))
    (match 0)
    (nlines 0)
    (current-line 0))
        (beginning-of-buffer)
        (while (not (eq (ignore-errors (save-excursion (re-search-forward pattern))) nil))
    (princ (my-search pattern) rslt)
    (incf nlines)
    (incf match)
    (if (= (line-number-at-pos)
           (save-excursion
         (progn
           (re-search-forward pattern)
           (point))))
        (progn (re-search-forward pattern)
           (incf match))))
    (message "%d matches in %d lines." match nlines)
    (switch-to-buffer "*Search Results*")))
```

---

## Test Data:

```
abacd
efgja
ogjfh
```

## Desired Outcome:

<kbd>M-x</kbd>`my-search-results a`

```el
;; Result: 
;; abacd
;; efgja

;; 3 matches in 2 lines.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your code as base and rewrote it somewhat.
The following function is *one possible* solution to solve that problem in one function:

```
(defun my-search-results (pattern)
  (interactive (list (read-regexp "Regex Pattern to Search for: ")))
  (let ((result-buffer (generate-new-buffer "*Search Results*"))
        (matches 0)
        (lines 0)
        (last-printed-line -1))
    (save-excursion
      (beginning-of-buffer)
      (while (re-search-forward pattern nil t)
        (incf matches)
        (let ((line-number-at-pos (line-number-at-pos)))
          (unless (= line-number-at-pos last-printed-line)
            (incf lines)
            (setq last-printed-line line-number-at-pos)
            (princ (thing-at-point 'line t) result-buffer)))))
    (switch-to-buffer "*Search Results*")
    (message "%d matches in %d lines." matches lines)))
```

*Notes about changes:*

- I moved `save-excursion` out of the loop, because this function call is expensive and would slow down the loop without benefit. This is also responsible, that `point` is locatet at the last match and I can get the current line number
- I compare current line number with the last printed line number to decide weather to increase `lines` and print, or not.
- I used `thing-at-point` to get the current line as a string
- I used available parameters of `re-search-forward` to suppress errors.

Comment: Is there a way to indicate cases where there is more than one match in a line? I tried changing the `unless` clause to `if` so that I can `princ` a standard text to indicate that, but wasn't able to make it work.

Comment: `(let ((line-number-at-pos (line-number-at-pos)))` seems like a smart way to make use of the same function symbol as a variable so that that `line-number-at-pos` can become the `last-printed-line`.

Comment: @Sati of course it is possible. Changing the `unless` to `if` is the right action. But changes depend on, what you want to print. If it is the number of occurences per line, before the line, then bigger changes would be necessary. You can use `edebug` to step through this function, to see how it works.

Comment: @sati `line-number-at-pos` thats one of the benefits of a lisp-2 language.